# Remove all records which are duplicate in spark dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, duplicates

I have a spark dataframe with multiple columns in it. I want to find out and remove rows which have duplicated values in a column (the other columns can be different).

I tried using `dropDuplicates(col_name)` but it will only drop duplicate entries but still keep one record in the dataframe. What I need is to remove all entries which were initially containing duplicate entries.

I am using Spark 1.6 and Scala 2.10.

Comment: [How to make good reproducible Apache Spark Dataframe examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48427185/how-to-make-good-reproducible-apache-spark-dataframe-examples)

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to remove all entries of those that are duplicated in a single column? Or they are duplicates when considering multiple columns?

Comment: @shaido yes, all entries of those that are duplicated in single column.

Comment: In scala that would be as follows, i guess there should by a similar way to do that in Python, hope this helps

- get the column names: 
val columns = df.schema.map(_.name)
- Run a foldLeft on that list of columns:
columns.foldLeft(df)((acc, elem) => acc.dropDuplicates(elem))

Comment: I saw you removed the pyspark tag and added you are using Scala, so I changed the answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would use window-functions for this. Lets say you want to remove duplicate `id` rows :

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

df
  .withColumn("cnt", count("*").over(Window.partitionBy($"id")))
  .where($"cnt"===1).drop($"cnt")
  .show()
```

Comment: I tried this with random generation of data and for that users should note that .persist could be relevant.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done by grouping by the column (or columns) to look for duplicates in and then aggregate and filter the results.

Example dataframe `df`:

```
+---+---+
| id|num|
+---+---+
|  1|  1|
|  2|  2|
|  3|  3|
|  4|  4|
|  4|  5|
+---+---+
```

Grouping by the `id` column to remove its duplicates (the last two rows):

```
val df2 = df.groupBy("id")
  .agg(first($"num").as("num"), count($"id").as("count"))
  .filter($"count" === 1)
  .select("id", "num")
```

This will give you:

```
+---+---+
| id|num|
+---+---+
|  1|  1|
|  2|  2|
|  3|  3|
+---+---+
```

---

Alternativly, it can be done by using a `join`. It will be slower, but if there is a lot of columns there is no need to use `first($"num").as("num")` for each one to keep them.

```
val df2 = df.groupBy("id").agg(count($"id").as("count")).filter($"count" === 1).select("id")
val df3 = df.join(df2, Seq("id"), "inner")
```

Comment: Since you are checking the count of grouped column == 1, can't the join be replaced by `first($"num").as("num")` ? It should result in the same output.

Comment: @philantrovert That is a good point, not sure how I missed that. I changed the answer to take that into account.

Comment: @shaido Your solution also worked fine, but i would like to avoid creating another dataframe for this problem, that's why accepting raphael's ans

Comment: @salmanbw The first approach will not create any extra dataframe though? The only difference is that this one uses `groupBy` and `agg` while his uses window functions to get the result.

Answer (score 2):

I added a `killDuplicates()` method to the open source [spark-daria](https://github.com/MrPowers/spark-daria) library that uses @Raphael Roth's solution.  Here's how to use the code:

```
import com.github.mrpowers.spark.daria.sql.DataFrameExt._

df.killDuplicates(col("id"))

// you can also supply multiple Column arguments
df.killDuplicates(col("id"), col("another_column"))
```

Here's the code implementation:

```
object DataFrameExt {

  implicit class DataFrameMethods(df: DataFrame) {

    def killDuplicates(cols: Column*): DataFrame = {
      df
        .withColumn(
          "my_super_secret_count",
          count("*").over(Window.partitionBy(cols: _*))
        )
        .where(col("my_super_secret_count") === 1)
        .drop(col("my_super_secret_count"))
    }

  }

}
```

You might want to leverage the spark-daria library to keep this logic out of your codebase.